# Finding latest date from JSON in python

Tags: python, json, datetime

I would like to find the latest endTime from a JSON output (requests) and fetch the "id" later for other actions.

Here is an example of my JSON

```
[
    {
        "endTime": "2020-08-14 20:19:34 CEST+0200",
        "id": "ecd1837a-7158-4abe-baa4-8ef15a09e4a7",
        "startTime": "2020-08-14 20:19:30 CEST+0200",
    },
    {
        "endTime": "2020-08-12 19:41:09 CEST+0200",
        "id": "ff0cd9dd-db90-4bfc-a783-bce0b98473be",
        "startTime": "2020-08-12 19:23:37 CEST+0200",
    },
    {
        "endTime": "2020-08-12 20:00:28 CEST+0200",
        "id": "f3cc6782-e40b-48f2-aa23-90f693961db8",
        "startTime": "2020-08-12 19:45:23 CEST+0200",
    }
]
```

This JSON is fetched as following:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=header, verify=False)
```

I'm having problems with the two following:

1- When trying to convert the endTime to datetime, what do I do with the leading " CEST+0200"? For the rest of the format, I believe I have it right with:

```
%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

2- How should I loop through all of the JSON endTime entries to compare them and fetch the latest value? Should I use a loop or is there a max function that would help?

It's my first time working with datetime, so my questions might seem a bit facile. My online research hasn't yielded anything concrete.

Comment: You can get rid of the `" CEST"` and then parse the remnants using `dateutil.parser.isoparse`. `dateutil.parser.isoparse("2020-08-14 20:19:34+0200")` ==> `datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 20, 19, 34, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script to get what you want.

```
from dateutil import parser

dates = [
    {
        "endTime": "2020-08-14 20:19:34 CEST+0200",
        "id": "ecd1837a-7158-4abe-baa4-8ef15a09e4a7",
        "startTime": "2020-08-14 20:19:30 CEST+0200",
    },
    {
        "endTime": "2020-08-12 19:41:09 CEST+0200",
        "id": "ff0cd9dd-db90-4bfc-a783-bce0b98473be",
        "startTime": "2020-08-12 19:23:37 CEST+0200",
    },
    {
        "endTime": "2020-08-12 20:00:28 CEST+0200",
        "id": "f3cc6782-e40b-48f2-aa23-90f693961db8",
        "startTime": "2020-08-12 19:45:23 CEST+0200",
    }
]

latest_date = sorted(dates, key=lambda i: i["endTime"], reverse=True)[0]

end_date_info = latest_date["endTime"].replace(" CEST", "")
date_time_converted = parser.isoparse(end_date_info)
print(date_time_converted, f"Type: {type(date_time_converted)}")
print(f"Latest date id: ", latest_date["id"])
```

Output:

```
2020-08-14 20:19:34+02:00 Type: <class 'datetime.datetime'>
Latest date id:  ecd1837a-7158-4abe-baa4-8ef15a09e4a7
```

Comment: what if the timestamp string contains something else than 'CEST', e.g. 'CET'? why not throw the whole string into `parser.parse`?

Comment: I think your dates list contains an element which is a string and is not a dictionary. Then It raises the error you mentioned. Could you provide or look at your dates_list?

Comment: Hey Hasan, the list is as seen in my original post. In the end, I've figured it out by taking the output of my requests.get, passing it with the json function to become readable, and then running the same steps provided earlier.